# Unable to deserialize json array using wcf service

Tags: json, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5, deserialization

I'm trying to DeSerialize data in json array using wcf service in the project. 
The data is fetched and can be noticed in the debugging but i'm unable to deserialize, or something else that I'm mistaken. Below is the code that I've tried to deserialize. 
**Note:-** I've separately run the wcf application and its returning json array in correct format with the actual result.

**HotelServiceClient.cs**

```
public class HotelServiceClient
    {
        private string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:50540/ServiceHotel.svc/";

        public List<HotelInfo> findall()
        {
            try
            {
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                var json = webClient.DownloadString(BASE_URL + "findall");
                var javaScriptJson = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return javaScriptJson.Deserialize<List<HotelInfo>>(json);

            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**HotelInfo.cs**

```
public class HotelInfo
    {
        private int _hotelid;
        private string _hotelname;
        private string _hoteldesc;
        private string _hotelprice;
        private byte[] _hotelpicture;


        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Id")]
        public int Hotelid
        {
            get
            {
                return _hotelid;
            }

            set
            {
                _hotelid = value;
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Hotelname
        {
            get
            {
                return _hotelname;
            }

            set
            {
                _hotelname = value;
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "description")]
        public string Hoteldesc
        {
            get
            {
                return _hoteldesc;
            }

            set
            {
                _hoteldesc = value;
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "price")]
        public string Hotelprice
        {
            get
            {
                return _hotelprice;
            }

            set
            {
                _hotelprice = value;
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "picture")]
        public byte[] Hotelpicture
        {
            get
            {
                return _hotelpicture;
            }

            set
            {
                _hotelpicture = value;
            }
        }


    }
```

**WebService**

**Hotel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CRUDwithHotels
{
    public class Hotel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public byte[] picture { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**IServiceHotel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace CRUDwithHotels
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IServiceHotel" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceHotel
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method ="GET", UriTemplate ="findall", ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Hotel> findall();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "find/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Hotel find(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "create", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool create(Hotel hotel);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "edit", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool edit(Hotel hotel);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "delete", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool delete(Hotel hotel);



    }
}
```

**ServiceHotel.svc.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace CRUDwithHotels
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "ServiceHotel" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select ServiceHotel.svc or ServiceHotel.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class ServiceHotel : IServiceHotel
    {
        public bool create(Hotel hotel)
        {
            using (ModelMyDemo hie = new ModelMyDemo())
            {
                try
                {
                    HotelInfoEntities info = new HotelInfoEntities();
                    info.Hotelname = hotel.Name;
                    info.Hoteldesc = hotel.description;
                    info.Hotelprice = hotel.price;
                    info.Hotelpicture = hotel.picture;
                    hie.HotelInfoEntities.Add(info);
                    hie.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }

        public bool delete(Hotel hotel)
        {
            using (ModelMyDemo hie = new ModelMyDemo())
            {
                try
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt16(hotel.Id);
                    HotelInfoEntities info = hie.HotelInfoEntities.Single(p => p.Hotelid == id);
                    hie.HotelInfoEntities.Remove(info);
                    hie.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }



        public bool edit(Hotel hotel)
        {
            using (ModelMyDemo hie = new ModelMyDemo())
            {
                try
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt16(hotel.Id);
                    HotelInfoEntities info = hie.HotelInfoEntities.Single(p => p.Hotelid == id);
                    info.Hotelname = hotel.Name;
                    info.Hoteldesc = hotel.description;
                    info.Hotelprice = hotel.price;
                    info.Hotelpicture = hotel.picture;
                    hie.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }

        public Hotel find(string id)
        {
            int hid = Convert.ToInt16(id);
            using (ModelMyDemo hie = new ModelMyDemo())
            {
                return hie.HotelInfoEntities.Where(pe => pe.Hotelid == hid).Select(pe => new Hotel
                {
                    Id = pe.Hotelid,
                    Name = pe.Hotelname,
                    description = pe.Hoteldesc,
                    price = pe.Hotelprice,
                    picture = pe.Hotelpicture

                }).First();
            };

        }

        public List<Hotel> findall()
        {

            //var imagesrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);
            using (ModelMyDemo hie = new ModelMyDemo())
            {
                return hie.HotelInfoEntities.Select(pe => new Hotel
                {
                    Id = pe.Hotelid,
                    Name = pe.Hotelname,
                    description = pe.Hoteldesc,
                    price = pe.Hotelprice,
                    picture = pe.Hotelpicture


               // picture = pe.Hotelpicture
                }).ToList();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Your `catch` block isn't very informative. Is the received json valid?

Comment: The json received is valid as i mentioned in the question. When i debug it, i get the correct json formatted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first we need an object in order to deserilize the the result in it.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<byte> picture { get; set; }
}
```

now all we need is to deserilize the json result in to the object. but your json is twice serilized so you need to deserilized it twice like this:

```
    public RootObject findall()
    {
        try
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(BASE_URL + "findall");
             return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);

        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using  OperationContract instead of DataContractor in wcf. and i also commented the byte property in HotelInfo class to check, yet it didn't serialize

Comment: please try my answer and if it didn't worked just post you json object.

Comment: How would i call this method in controller class? Like previously i used
HotelServiceClient client = new HotelServiceClient();
ViewBag.listHotels = client.findall();
 return View();

Comment: just post json value from var json = webClient.DownloadString(BASE_URL + "findall");

Comment: Alright i managed to call the method. Now it gives an exception upon the var objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(mStrm) that "There was an error deserializing the object of type Travel.Models.Hotel.HotelInfo. Encountered unexpected character 'h'."

Comment: the json value is 
"[{\"Id\":5,\"Name\":\"dsf\",\"description\":\"dsfsdfsdf\",\"picture\":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,...] The picture bytes are too long so i just put some bytes.

Comment: dear @user100020 i updated my answer. i hope it could solve your problem.

Comment: Sir, i tried your code but it again caught null value upon object string that you deserialized on the third line. Further more, all the properties values are displayed in the debugging except the price property which is invisible.

Comment: i tested my code and it works just fine. is there any way you can log the json string? i guess something is wrong with your json string.

Comment: As i mentioned in my previous comments, the json formatting looks correct to me and when i run wcf service separately, it also generates the correct form of json array.

Comment: is this a public web service? can i call it? please provide a required information so i can help you.

Comment: no Sir, its not a public website. I made it myself. if you want i can share files here.

Comment: I'm sorry dear @user100020. i don't think i can help you any more. i just vote up your question and  hope you can solve it. good luck

Comment: Ok. you are calling your findall method and it returns array of hotels. please try my updated code and let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: This time its not catching any error, but not even setting values in the properties.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know why the properties are null.

Comment: Sir your answer is correct and I've recreated another properties class, and this time it worked. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: What does request entity too large means? I'm encountering the error in create method.